# How to use the index of one <li> in identifying a corresponding <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers, indexing, html-lists

Been working on this problem and I am frustrated with not having a solid comprehension on how to create a pointer and instantiation of a pointer via jQuery.

I have two lists:

```
<div class="listSet">
    <ul id="list1">
        <li>One bug <a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li>Two bug <a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li>Three bug <a href="#">X</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div class="listSet">  
    <ul id="list2">
        <li><img src="bug1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="bug2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="bug3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am using the capture of the click on the first list to give me the index of that unordered list:

```
var theBox = $(this).parents('li');
theBoxInd = $('#list ul li').index(theBox);
```

How do I get a handle on the corresponding LI in the second list?  I wanted to remove them from the screen, but can not seem to replicate the idea of having the index of the second list to be able to `.remove()` the two LIs.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method and the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to achieve this:

```
$("#list1 li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $li = $(this).parent();
    $("#list2 li:eq(" + $li.index() + ")").add($li).remove();
});
```

This will remove both `li` elements with the same `index`

**Working Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/cttZn/5/

---

Or you could use the `:nth-child` selector like this:

```
$("#list1 li a").click(function() {
    var child = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    $("#list1, #list2").find("li:nth-child(" + child + ")").remove();
});
```

**Working Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/cttZn/8/

Comment: to add a bit of clarity for the difference between `:eq()` and `:nth-child()`: `eq` is the zero-based index of the elements, while `nth-child` is the one-based index of the elements. `nth-child` can also accept formulas like `2n+3` or `even`.

Comment: First of all - thanks for the help.  I checked out the jsfiddle and saw the result.  I was looking at the code on your first example - and am not clear on: 1) preventDefault() but will look it up. 2) By having the li have a dollar sign, is this a form of pointer? 3) the :eq is the indexing service using zero-based (as -zzzzBov said).  And as I read it - you are finding the index of the clicked on li - then adding it to the second list li.  Then removing them both.  Thanks.

Comment: In the second example, you now are connecting both lists and finding the child (index+1) and removing them both.  Have not seen this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sanford 1) `preventDefault()` prevents the action of the anchor tag being clicked. 2) using `$` as a prefix is something I use as a standard to signify that this variable is already a jQuery object. 3) that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$('#list1 > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    var corresp = $('#list2 > li').eq(idx);
    alert(corresp.children('img').attr('src'));
    // to remove the <li> element: corresp.remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/yM3aD/

Comment: ThiefMaster - what are the greater-than signs?  And intrigued by the corresp.children function.

Comment: The select only direct descendants. And `corresp` is the li; to get the img inside it, I'm using children(). But if you want to delete the whole li, remove the alert line completely and only call `corresp.remove();`